# Billing charges for use of Google Sheets API

Tags: google-api, beagleboneblack, google-sheets-api

I am currently posting sensor data to a spreadsheet in my GoogleDrive, from a Beaglebone Black development board, following this [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/dht-humidity-sensing-on-raspberry-pi-with-gdocs-logging/connecting-to-googles-docs-updated) at Adafruit. The frequency of posting to the sheet is planned to be maybe 2-10 times an hour, 24/7. Only I will be viewing the data charted from the spreadsheet.

Browsing around my API Console IAM & Admin, there appears to be means of logging data usage, and although my spreadsheet continues to be populated with data, there appears no change at Console.

So, I am new to this, and was curious at what point will I begin to incur charges using these APIs?

Thank you,
Mark

Comment: This looks off-topic to me as this isn't really a programming question.  Perhaps you should send a message to Google?

Comment: Was directed here by a link provided by Google on one of their QA/FAQ pages. Did not find there what I was looking for.

Comment: We can certainly (try to) help you on how to use the API.  We can't really give you charging information on it.

Comment: Help me to understand what I am seeing, or rather, not seeing, in the API Console in re data usage?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is about google API billing.

Comment: The documentation should be consulted:  https://developers.google.com/sheets/limits

Comment: Are we to assume that this means that the sheets API is 1) free to use and that it 2) limits usage as described here 3) automatically (ie. it's is not the case that you can go over these limits, but would then have to pay for that (which would again beg the question of what explicitly is the billing plan for the sheets API or is it totally free as described here))?